# how to specify weights for different roles in apache mesos

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

i would like to understand the concept of weights for different roles in mesos and where to specify that. I have used --weights parameter while starting the mesos-master. But it didn't work. I want to know like if for a particular role, if we give weight as 2.0, how does the resource allocation change compared to default weight of 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? You can validate that you have changed the configuration of weights by querying the "/weights" master endpoint: https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/master/weights/

Comment: I didn't see any change in the way resources where allocated when i changed the weights for different roles. I wanted to know if I specify more weight for a particular role, how does it help that role.